# Parsing error - Java strips quotes (") in a JSON string sent as a command line argument

Tags: java, json, batch-file

I have a batch file which writes a JSON to a `temp.txt` file and passes this string as a command line argument to a Java application.

The batch script:

```
java -jar "path/to/jar/MyJar.jar" > temp.txt
SET /p _json=<temp.txt

java -jar "path/to/jar/MyOtherJar.jar" %_json% 
PAUSE
```

The `MyJar.jar` outputs the JSON and writes it to the `temp.txt` and `MyOtherJar` takes the JSON as argument.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Key1": "5d078",
    "Key2": "5d079",
    "list2": ["abc", "def"],
    "list1": ["xyz", "aaa"],
    "Size": 2
}
```

The Java application tries to convert the received string into a `JSONObject` like this:

```
String jsonString = args[0];
try {
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I execute the batch script I am getting this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']' at 78 [character 79 line 1]
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:127)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:366)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:214)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:321)
        at de.iese.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:17)
```

After printing the `jsonString` it shows that the entire String is getting parsed without the double quotes i.e.,

```
{
    Key1: 5d078,
    Key2: 5d079,
    list2: [abc, def],
    list1: [xyz, aaa],
    Size: 2
}
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? I am not very familiar with cmd scripts but is there a way to bypass this writing to a txt file and directly store this is a variable and send it to `MyOtherJar`?

Comment: Are you trying to parse the same json as in question? Coz the exception message says character 79, line 1. It seems like the JSON you're receiving as input is probably malformed. Can you log the input string and check if it's a valid json?

Comment: I would put a print line under the initialization of `jsonString`. Maybe the full jsonString isn't getting loaded?

Comment: Yes, the JSON that I posted is what I am reading from the `temp.txt`. I copied the `temp.txt` contents and JSONLint says it's a valid JSON.

Comment: @RobOhRob, I tried your suggestion. It seems that the jsonString is getting passed on to the Java application without the double quotes. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Post the code where you are reading the temp.txt

Comment: maybe you need to escape those double quotes with \" .. since you are passing content as args quotes may be truncated.. alternatively try reading the content through FileInputStream or similar

Comment: I think you would need to remove new line characters and send it as in one single line ( string ) to make it work as an argument

Comment: @TechFree, I tried that but the error remains the same. It is still being passed without the double quotes.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis, I'm sorry but I am not very familiar with batch script. Any idea how I can escape those in the batch itself? Also, using FileInputStream is not an option for me as it  is a requirement that I execute the two jars using a batch file.

Comment: @jackw, I added the answer. Pls see if this works, tweak accordingly.

Comment: @jackw - you replace each " with \" in the file - it may work this way - since then it is being added as a string which starts and ends with double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input file **test.txt** contains:

```
{
    "Key1": "5d078",
    "Key2": "5d079",
    "list2": ["abc", "def"],
    "list1": ["xyz", "aaa"],
    "Size": 2
}
```

This WIN batch script code read the input file line by line, and append to a variable called **data** in the example below.
When invoking the Java class/or executable library, wrap the input data in double quotes as your program reads only one argument ( spaces would span the input without double quotes into multiple arguments ). The example below justs runs a standalone class to test this out, and uses **"org.json"** library dependency.

```
@echo off
set data=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   call set "data=%%data%% %%a"
)
set CLASSPATH=.;json-20180813.jar
java test.JsonObjectConversion "%data%" 
pause
```

Now reading the program would look like:

```
//single argument beaing read by Java
 String json = args[0];
 try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    //object be read properly now
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
 } catch (Exception e) {
      //no exception should come here
 }
```